# Firebug's console.log prints unexpected value using javaScript

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am new to javascript and was playing with simple code but when i wrote this  below specified code in firebug, i got the unexpected value.
Here is the code

```
    var a=5;
    while(a<10000){
       if(a%1000==0)
         console.log(a);
       a++;
    }
```

And this was the output in console

```
    var a=5; while(a<10000){   if(a%1000==0)     console.log(a);   a++; }
    1000
    2000
    3000
    4000
    5000
    6000
    7000
    8000
    9000
    9999
```

*At the end it gave me the "9999", which it should not have printed according to the logic.*
While, i replaced the *console.log* by *alert*, i received the exact output.
I feel it is simple, but i have never used firebug and i was a little curious to know about why this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that firebug does always print the return value of the last statement. If you change your statement to this:

```
var a=5; while(a<10000){   if(a%1000==0)     console.log(a);   a++; };null;
```

you will get `null` instead of `9999`. The `9999` is the return value of the last `a++`. This is only if you enter you code in the console, and so you can just enter a variable and its printed.

Comment: I've [added a note to the documentation](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Command_Line) clarifying this.

Comment: The chrome debugger has similar behavior.

Comment: Actually, all browser devtools do this.

Answer (score 2):

> The console has the ability to print the last value that is not being used in `console.log`.

**`9999` is  not a `output` but the last value of `a`**

The same behavior you will observe in `Chrome-console`. The last value printed is the value interpreted for the last statement.

Comment: FWIW, also the console in the Firefox DevTools does this.